# Pure State Non-zero Entropy Paradox

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Entropy measures the number of microscopic states of a given system.

For a pure state, the count is one. Thus, entropy ~ log(1) = zero.

However, on the other hand, if we calculate the entropy of finding a particle in real space.
It will not be zero.
[image: pure state entropy paradox]

My question is, what is the entropy of such pure state? Is it zero or not? Then what about my idea to calculate it in real space distribution?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is, what is the entropy of such pure state? Is it zero or not? Then what about my idea to calculate it in real space distribution?

Comment: Is this paradox occurs because the "subsystem" of your division is invalid or because they are correlated? I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The new divided four boxes are not a complete basis.
Quantum states have more information than real position distributions.

The pure state is zero entropy.
Although we still have some sort of uncertainty on position,
this uncertainty comes purely from the quantum uncertainty, **which can never be known**,
thus entropy does not include this term.